# Invalid syntax while using socket

Tags: python, sockets

i've struggled with this code and I can't see why its saying there is a syntax error on line 15. Im trying to create a TCP connection with google for a diagnostic tool for my college coursework.

```python
import socket 
import sys

#defining the port and host we wll be using to check the internet connection on.
remote_connection = "www.google.com" #google will automatically load balance the request to the uk servers.
port = 80

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as err:
    print("The script has exited with error %s" %(err))

try:
    sockettest = socket.gethostbyname(remote_connection)
if socket.gaierror:
    # this means that the connection is possibly blocked by a firewall and we will tell the end user.
print("there was an error resolving the host, possibly a firewall issue") 
sys.exit()
elif socket.timeout:
    #the connection has timedout which probably means the internet is offline
print("Your internet connection is offline, please connect all cables, reboot any network equiptment and try again")
sys.exit()

# connecting to the server
s.connect((remote_connection,port))

print("Your internet connection is active and working correctly! \n\
I was able to connect to:", (remote_connection), "sucessfully")
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting and what have you tried to correct it?

Comment: @rjp invalid syntax

Answer (score 5):

There is no `except` statement for

```
try:
    sockettest = socket.gethostbyname(remote_connection)
```

Comment: Indentation around `if socket.gaierror:` needs to be fixed as well